# Visual studio shows files that I never committed and that are not in the repo as "commited"

Tags: git, visual-studio

Check this screenshot:

[image]

These files are not in the history of commits:

```
$ git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -u

.gitignore
.gitmodules
Core/App.config
Core/config/config.yml.example
Core/config/scenarios.yml.example
... // other files
```

When I click the files to try and open them an error is thrown "File <> does not exist in the project directory".

***Question***: where are these files from and how should I get rid of them?

Comment: What does the tooltip say when you move over those attention icons? Pretty sure they are in the solution file but missing from the file system.

Comment: It says "checked in"

Comment: Can you *open* the files…?

Comment: I have found them in the solution file. Can you submit that as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why Visual Studio would tell you in the tooltip that they are “checked in” (to be fair, the Git integration into the solution explorer is… sometimes weird).

But in general, the exclamation icon there means that the files are physically missing. If you try to open them, you should be able to confirm that (since you won’t be able to open them).

So why are they listed there? Probably because they are listed in the project file listed as explicit files although they don’t exist. If you remove them there, or remove them using the context menu, they will be gone from the solution explorer.